# Is there a C++ equivalent of WaitforSingleObject?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, waitforsingleobject

I need to rewrite some code that uses the windows WaitforSingleObject function.

```
myEvent = CreateEvent( NULL, FALSE, FALSE, szName );
WaitForSingleObject( myEvent, nMilliseconds );
```

I need to wait for an event or for a timeout to happen.
Is there an equivalent to this in straight C++??

I am using STL C++11 and not any other libraries such as boost.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

Comment: Please clarify the question. Depends on what library you use. stl? boost? The C++ language has no integrated OS features, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: If you use STL C++11 threads, yes

Comment: @AntonSavin I have looked at your example and ran it but I cant see how I can wait for the mutex OR a timeout at the same time

Comment: @HarryBoy http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_until

Comment: Ahh just see wait_untill :)

Comment: @HarryBoy Given the name `nMilliseconds` in the sample code, you probably want [`wait_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for) instead of `wait_until`.

Comment: Here is the exactly solution you are looking for: https://github.com/moya-lang/Event/blob/master/Event.h The code is C++11 and fully mimics WINAPI Event Objects

Answer (score 6):

You can't use C++11 thread routines with win32 threads (unless you heavily mess up with mingw thread implementations, something I would not recommend) and there's no standard C++ equivalent to an OS-specific API call.

You can, however use C++11 threads and use [condition variables](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) (cfr. *waiting*) to accomplish the same thing that [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx) does, i.e.

- Wait for an object to be in a signaled state
- Wait until a timeout elapses

Edit: specifically you would need [wait_until](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_until)

Comment: The equivalent of the API call would be `wait_for`, not `wait_until`.

Comment: Can Visual Studio's `<thread>` be safely mixed with winapi threads?

Comment: "mess up with mingw thread" - this is not just a mingw thing. VS also implements the `<thread>` library and equally, mixing Win32 and C++ threads can cause adverse issues - they are not automatically compatible. IIRC, VS uses the ConcRT to implement the C++ threading components.

Comment: Some mingw builds do use windows thread model, can't remember which ones but it might be pretty common anyway

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use C++11 Only. Here is an example (too long to be pasted here): https://github.com/moya-lang/Event/blob/master/Event.h. The code fully mimics WINAPI Event Objects so this is something you are asking for.